# Conditions in useEffect React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, react-hooks

I have a **useEffect** that subscribes to websocket at startup and adds the data that comes from the server to the **operationList** list. This list is displayed on the webpage. This is a list of operations performed by construction equipment, which I receive online and could not chage on a backend.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/')
  ws.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
    const response = JSON.parse(e.data)
      setOperationsList(operationsList => [
      response,
      ...operationsList,
    ]);

  })
  ws.onopen = () => {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
    action: "subscribe_to_operations_activity",
    request_id: new Date().getTime(),
  }))
  }
}, [])
```

In the same component I have a state, which stores information about the id of the equipment, the report on which is currently displayed on the screen.

```
const [activeID, setActiveID]  = useState(false)
```

I need to add to the operationsList not all the data that comes in the server, as it is done now **response = JSON.parse(e.data)**. Instead, I need to check the condition **response.id == activeID**, and to add to **operationsList** only those data that satisfy the condition. I can't add **activeID** to the list of useEffect dependencies because in this case, a new WebSocket subscription will be created every time the **activeID** changes. I understand that most likely I don't understand some basic things, so I would be grateful for any advice

Added the **activeID** path:

In my component

```
const [activeID, setActiveID]  = useState(false)

  const getElementStar = (newID) => {
  setActiveID(newID)
}
```

Then I pass it to child component as props:

```
<LeftMenu
  ...
  getElementStar={getElementStar}
  ...
/>
```

And finally in child component

```
  const getKey = () => {
    const newID = props.item.id
    props.getElementStar(newID)
  }

  return (
    <ListItemButton sx={{ pl: 4 }} key={props.index} onClick={getKey}>
      <ListItemIcon>
        { props.star === props.index ? <Star/> : <StarBorder/> }
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={props.item.name} />
    </ListItemButton>
  );
```

Comment: don't forget to disconnect when the component unmounts. see [useEffect Effects with Cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup).

Comment: Please, tell me where exactly I forgot. I'm new in frontend, so I could not see some basic things

Comment: in `useEffect` you can return a cleanup function, for example `useEffect(_ => { /* subscribe here */ return () => { /* unsubscribe here */ }})`. See [Example Using Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it everywhere in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How `activeID` is supposed to change?
Basically, storing something in a state implies that the component need a re-render when this value changes. Which does not seem to be your case here?

So I would suggest to have your `activeID` stored as a `ref`

```
const activeID = useRef('[my id]')

useEffect(() => {
  const ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/')
  ws.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
    const response = JSON.parse(e.data)
      
      setOperationsList(operationsList => [
      ...response.filter(o => o.id === activeID.current),
      ...operationsList,
    ]);

  })
  ws.onopen = () => {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
    action: "subscribe_to_operations_activity",
    request_id: new Date().getTime(),
  }))
  }
}, [])
```

If activeID needs to change somehow, you can have this by doing

```
useEffect(() => {
    activeID.current = [my new value]
}, [triggers that could change activeId (maybe a prop?)])
```

=== EDIT ===

So I assume changing `activeID` must trigger a re-render to change your `<Star >` component depending on current `activeID` right? :)

So I would suggest 2 differents things. Either with the `ref`, so something like that

```
const [activeID, setActiveID] = useState();
const activeIDRef = useRef()
```

on your `useEffect` having

```
ws.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
    const response = JSON.parse(e.data)

      setOperationsList(operationsList => [
      ...response.filter(o => o.id === activeIDRef.current),
      ...operationsList,
    ]);
})
```

and have a second `useEffect` to change ref when `activeID` changes

```
useEffect(() => {
    activeIDRef.current = activeID
}, [activeID])
```

**OR**

Maybe it would be easier to keep on storing everything in your `operationsList` BUT having it filtered when displaying values. If you need it in a state, like this

```
const [operationsListFiltered, setOperationsListFiltered] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    setOperationsListFiltered(operationsList.filter(o => o.id === activeId))
}, [activeId, operationsList])
```

Or directly as variable

```
const operationsListFiltered = useMemo(() => operationsList.filter(o => o.id === activeId), [activeId, operationsList]);
```

This way, either your `activeID` OR your `operationLists` from your websocket changes, your `operationsListFiltered` will be updated

Comment: **activeID** changes when a user press a button to change a report table of a particulat item from an equiopment list. I pass a callback function to another component to make it change. Unforteantely, it seems that changes in activeID is not represented in my useEffect.

Comment: Could you share this piece of code?

Comment: Oh, I think it will be more readable if you edit your question instead of posting it in a comment which don't have proper formatting :p

Comment: Sorry :) Tried to format if using stackoverflow comment formatting tips

Comment: Updated the initial post

Comment: Yes, thank you for such attention to my pain. The only question is why we filter **...operationsList.filter(o => o.id === activeIDRef.current)**? The problem is to filter **response**, because the problem is to get new elements requires the condition **response.id == activeID**. Or maybe I just didn't get the idea?

Comment: Yes sorry, I didn't pay attention to this, you have to indeed filter the response `[...response.filter(o => o.id === activeIDRef.current), ...operationsList]`
I've updated my answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can try running a loop with a condition that, once true, will then push what you want to push to the specific list. That will only work if the data you are receiving from the back-end is a type of array.

```
let dataList = []

    const loopData = () => {
       e.data.forEach((obj) => {
         if (obj.id === activeID) {
            dataList.push(obj)
         } 
       }
    }

useEffect(() => loopData(), []);
```

And then

```
setOperationsList(...dataList)
```

Comment: Yes, I recieve data as a list of objects. But is it possible to locate the first code sample inside the **useEffect** hook? And do you mean that **useOperationList** in your answer is equivelent to my **setOperationsList**?

Comment: Yes, sorry - I meant setOperationsList instead of useOperationList. I believe that you might wrap this forEach loop in a function that will be called on useEffect, should work! I will edit my post in a second.